# Asp.net Identity GetUsersByRole stopped working after version 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have the following method being used to get all users by a role and it was working fine until version 2.0 was released. Has something changed? Role no longer exists, only RoleId but that isn't useful as I need to access by name... appears Microsoft removed/moved this to a different class? Can't find it anywhere though.

```
    public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsersByRole(string userRole)
    {
        return (_accountRepository.Get.SelectMany(user => user.Roles, (user, role) => new { user, role })
            .Where(x => x.role.Role.Name == userRole).Select(x => x.user)).ToList();
    }
```

the Role object in x.role.Role.Name no longer resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Role/User navigation properties on `IdentityUserRole` were removed in version 2.0, a workaround would be to write your own linq query at the appropriate db context specific layer to get the list of users in a particular role.  Longer term, we will be adding a `GetUsersInRole` method to `RoleManager` (tentatively should be in 2.1).

Comment: Any idea ETA on 2.1 this is bit silly it was removed and now being added back in.

Comment: It should be in the nightly builds shortly in alpha form, but no eta on RTM, its not being added back in the same way (on the POCO), but it will be exposed off of the RoleManager instead